# function as parameter in MariaDB query

Tags: sql, database, mariadb

I have the following code in Maria DB ,

I want to use my function in a query to create a sequence that starts with the count(*) +1 of a my TABLE1

It gives me an error in the CREATE SEQUENCE query :

```
    CREATE FUNCTION myFuntion() RETURNS INT
    BEGIN
       DECLARE lastID INT DEFAULT 1;
       SELECT COUNT(*) INTO lastID FROM TABLE1;
       RETURN lastID+1;
    END;
    
   CREATE SEQUENCE seq101 START WITH myFuntion() INCREMENT BY 1 ;
```

Error :

> MySqlError { ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
> the right syntax to use near 'myFuntion() INCREMENT BY 1'  }

Comment: You probably need to give the start value as an integer literal. What does the manual say?

Comment: The official website says that its un INT but in my case I want to use the result of my function in the query , the problem here is What is the method to put it in the query.

Comment: You can't. It just isn't supported to evaluate the start value at execution time. What you can do is write an app that generates the statement. Select the max value, use your programming language to build the related create sequence statement, then run it.

Comment: Is there any solution in mariaDB that can create sequence and give a parameter ( like a count query of a table ) to START BY ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way is to use a prepared statement and a variable, since user functions are not allowed in PREPARE FROM/EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

```
SELECT count(*) + 1 INTO @lastid FROM yourtable
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONCAT("CREATE SEQUENCE seq101 START WITH ", @lastid," INCREMENT BY 1");
```